# What is the usage for \w?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string: `string-a`

I'm trying to match this string with the following regex: `string-\w{1,2}`. I'd like to match anything in the form of "string-aa" where 'aa' can be one or two of any letter or digit.

But running `'string-a'.match('string-\w{1,2}');` returns `null` in the console. Why does that happen? If I run this in a debugging tool like [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/), it works perfectly fine.

I'm not sure I understand how \w is used. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are matching as a text not regular expression. you should change it to:

```
'string-a'.match(/string-(\w{1,2})/);
```

Comment: Thanks Damian. In PHP, everything is passed as a string, and that's where my wires got crossed. Will mark the answer in 4 minutes (once I'm allowed).

Answer (score -1):

For `'string-a'.match('string-\w{1,2}');` to work in the console you need to escape the `\`.

So try,
`'string-a'.match('string-\\w{1,2}');` and it will work.

The `\w` is used as you may expect, it matches a word character.